# How to find the date difference in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a `passed_date` column in table , I wants to find the difference between this date and current date, And have to check whether this difference is >365days?  for example 'passed_date' column consists   09/26/2013 09:16:48.000 PM . How can I find the difference between the date ?

```
sqlcommand cmd = new sqlcommand("select passed_date from table");
cmd.executereader();
dr.read();
sring date1 = stdr[0].tostring();
string date2 = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

Comment: Use TimeSpan in C# or DATADIFF in SQL Server

Comment: What did you try? You are probably not the first person trying to solve this problem, did you google?

Answer (score 2):

This uses index:

```
Select passed_date from table where passed_date > Dateadd(day,-365,getdate())
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
select passed_date from table where DateDiff(day,passed_date,GetDate()) > 365
```

Comment: This will cause slow performance. @AmirrezaKeshavarz posted a better answer

Answer (score 1):

try this ...

```
declare @startDate datetime
set @startdate = DATEADD(day, -365, GETDATE())
-- or set @startDate = DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
select passed_date, datediff(day, passed_date, getdate()) from table where passed_date > @startDate
```

... if you want a solution in t-sql

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :-

```
SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("select passed_date from table", con);
var date = sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar();
DateTime startDate = (DateTime)date;
DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan span = endDate.Subtract(startDate);

double days = span.TotalDays;
if (365 < days)
{
    ********your logic ************************     
}
```